# How to pixelize / add pixelating effect to a UIImage in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, image-processing, uiimage

I am looking for a way to pixelize a UIImage in Cocoa touch. I don't know what the best approach would be (some people have suggested me using OpenGL) but I have a feeling there must exist some other simple way I may be overlooking. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I perform a fast pixellation filter on an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049041/how-do-i-perform-a-fast-pixellation-filter-on-an-image)

Answer (score 4):

Signal processing explanation of what to do to the image:

1. [Downsample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/downsample.html) by N
2. [Upsample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/upsample.html) by N
3. Then [convolve](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/conv2.html) the image with a NxN box filter (Matlab code to create NxN box filter`rect = ones(N,N)`).

Comp sci explanation:

1. create an empty new image that is the same size
2. iterate over every Nth pixel in the original image
3. repeat every Nth pixel in the new image