# How to pixelate an UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, image-processing, uiimage

are there any filters to pixelate an image programmatically in iOS?

If not, how can i pixelate an image in easy way?

thanks.

---

Like pixel effect on [eBay app for iPad](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ebay-for-ipad/id364203371?mt=8) (menu drag to open, on the top left)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean pixelize, you can take a look at both these links

[How to pixelize / add pixelating effect to a UIImage in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853376/how-to-pixelize-add-pixelating-effect-to-a-uiimage-in-ios)

or

[How do I perform a fast pixellation filter on an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049041/how-do-i-perform-a-fast-pixellation-filter-on-an-image)

Answer (score 1):

How about the use the `Core Image` filter named `CIPixellate`? 
I posted the code snippet in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29835046/1978096) of [How do I perform a fast pixellation filter on an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049041/how-do-i-perform-a-fast-pixellation-filter-on-an-image)