# Pixelate effect for images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiimage, imagefilter

I need to apply a filter like Pixelate or Blur to a portion of UIimage.
Though its working fine with filter **CIPixellate** but the problem is this filter is available for ios 6 or later.

I hope there's an expert out there who can help me with this:

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have a question? This is a question and answer site, not a general forum.

Comment: ye the question is how to Pixelate an image in ios5.

Answer (score 0):

[GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) can do this for you. It is an open source framework, compatible with iOS 5.0+, with the added benefit that it does the image rendering work on the GPU so it's much faster and comes with a filter for pixelating images.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049041/how-do-i-perform-a-fast-pixellation-filter-on-an-image) for more details.